# RecyclerView item's X and Y are 0 when clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In a `RecyclerView`, I'm trying to get the clicked item's X and Y position.
This is inside my adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AlfabetoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       // setImage(holder.imageButton, images.get(position));

        holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.getX(); // This is 0, but it shouldn't be!
                view.getY(); // This is also 0.
                executaSomAnimacaoLetra(sounds.get(position), Utils.getResourceFromFile(popups.get(position), context), view); // I do some stuff here
            }
        });


    }
```

Thing is, both X an Y always return 0, and they shouldn't. I need the X an Y of the clicked item to do some animations.

I already tried getting the X and Y position inside of an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` and inside of an `OnPreDrawListener` (both work when you need the X and Y on the activity's onCreate), but they also return 0.

I'm using the `GridLayoutManager` on my `RecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(Activity_alfabeto.this, 7, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, but what about a little thread on the rootview as: `view.post(new Runnable() { ... view.getX(); view.getY(); });` to let the UI to be displaying, did you try?

Comment: Tried that already, it didn't work. Actually I just figured out what was happening, will post the answer, but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it working. I had to use this approach:

```
int[] originalPos = new int[2];
view.getLocationInWindow(originalPos);
//originalPos[0] is my X
//originalPos[1] is my Y
```

**Here getX and getY are relative to the view's parent, not their absolute position on the screen.**

```
    view.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos);
```

Could also be used.

Comment: It works only when I don't scroll the recycler view. When I scroll - it gives me wrong coordinates

Comment: @tieorange you might want to take into account the ammount of scroll that has been done to the RecyclerView. Can't look at it right now, but it's worth a try!

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me:

```
view.getRawX()
view.getRawY()
```